# Why Is Fortify Smithing Doing Nothing?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am playing Skyrim on my 360 and I have both Smithing and Enchanting at level 100 and Alchemy somewhere around level 50. To create some daedra armour I created a fortify smithing potion (67%) and fortify smithing apparel (falmer helmet, ring, necklace and gloves each at 21%) and I also have Krosis. Yet when I go to create my daedra armour the stats dont increase from where they are when I dont wear these items or drink the potion (for example the daedric armour stays at armour = 50).

Does anyone know why this is and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 14):

Fortify smithing has only an effect on weapons and armors if you are improving an item.

As you can see [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRzvwHc_Yzo) at 7:50 the weapon he's smithing deals only 32 damage even with item that add 10000000% smithing. But after he improves it it deals a lot of damage.

(found under the improvement table [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Smithing).)
Alchemy and Enchanting can improve results significantly via the Fortify Smithing effect allowing for greater improvements at a given level than the table shows. Combining both Alchemy and Enchanting to improve one another and then combining both to improve Smithing as much as possible can be very powerful. The relevant Alchemy Tips page or Enchanting page have more information on how to get the most out of those skills.

Comment: yup, the boost only kicks in when improving, making items always results in the base item so there's no armor/damage difference